# How to do two-way binding on a radio button Blazor child component

Tags: radio-button, blazor, parent-child, blazor-webassembly, two-way-binding

I'm trying to create a radio button component in Blazor that has two way data binding but I can't seem to get the value (testNumber) on the parent to change. I am new to Blazor and C#, so any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

**ChildComp.razor**

```
<div>
    <label for="radio1">1</label>
    <input 
        id="radio1"
        type="radio"
        value="1"
        name="test"
        checked="@(_selectedGroup == 1)"
        @onclick="@(() => _selectedGroup = 1)"/>

    <label for="radio2">2</label>
    <input
        id="radio2"
        type="radio"
        value="2"
        name="test"
        checked="@(_selectedGroup == 2)"
        @onclick="@(() => _selectedGroup = 2)"/>

</div>

@code {

    private int _selectedGroup = 0;

    [Parameter]
    public int BindingValue
    {
        get => _selectedGroup;
        set
        {
            if (_selectedGroup == value ) 
            {
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                _selectedGroup = value;
            }
            BindingValueChanged.InvokeAsync(value);
        }
    }

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<int> BindingValueChanged { get; set; }   
}
```

**ParentComp.razor**

```
<div>
    <ChildComp @bind-BindingValue="testNumber" />
    <h5>@testNumber</h5> 
</div>

@code {

    int testNumber = 0;
}
```

Comment: I have the same issue. Any luck?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you probably noticed `bind` does not work with radio buttons. On GitHub you can see the discussion about it [here](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/5579). It's sad that Blazor doesn't support these simple features...

I had the same problem and came across this [solution](https://dev.to/j_sakamoto/workaround-how-to-two-way-data-binding-of-radio-button-input-with-blazor-spa-v050-31fd):

```cs
@code {
    public int EditionCode = 1;

    // "Edition" class has "int Code" and "string Text" properties.
    public Edition[] Editions = new [] {
      new Edition { Code = 1, Text = "Home" },
      new Edition { Code = 2, Text = "Pro" },
      new Edition { Code = 3, Text = "Enterprise" },
    };
}

@foreach (var edition in this.Editions)
{
<label>
  <input type="radio" 
         name="edition"
         checked="@(EditionCode == edition.Code)"
         onchange="@(() => EditionCode = edition.Code)"/>
         @edition.Text
</label>
}
```

If this solution doesn't solve your needs, then have a look [here](https://www.meziantou.net/creating-a-inputselect-component-for-enumerations-in-blazor.htm) (a bit more complex).

Answer (score 0):

I have this code that works for me:

```
    @foreach (var radiobtn in this.radioButtons)
    {
        <div>
            <input type="radio" name="technology" id="@radiobtn.Id" value="@radiobtn.Value" @onchange="RadioSelection"
                   checked=@(string.Equals(radiobtn, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) />

            <label for="@radiobtn">@radiobtn.Text</label>
        </div>
    }
```

in code behind

```
public string paymentDuration = string.Empty;

public RadioButton[] radioButtons = new[]
{
  new RadioButton { Id=1, Value = 1, Text = "1 month" },
  new RadioButton { Id=2, Value = 12, Text = "12 months" }
};

public void RadioSelection(ChangeEventArgs args)
{
    paymentDuration = args.Value.ToString();
}

public class RadioButton
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string? Text { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
    public bool Selected { get; set; } = false;
}
```